# Little mistake somewhere. Help needed

Tags: javascript, html, random, user-experience

I wrote a little browser-game.

The rules are easy: you have 15 seconds to decide if you know the name written on the screen.

You have two buttons: "i know"/"give up" - depends on what you want to choose.

If you choose "give up" (or time ends) photo 1 appears. Otherwise, photo 2 will be shown.

Whole operation is looped.

Here's my question: I wanted to choose random name from array "word" every single round, so I wrote function "random_word()". I put it into "timer()", "surrender()" and "winning()" functions. But it doesn't work.

I'm just starting with programming, so I'll be grateful for possibly easiest to understand code. Thanks for all help.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
<script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
</head>
<body> 
<button id= "btnSurrender">give up</button>

<button id= "btnWinning">i know</button>

<p id="seconds">15</p>
<div id="photo"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">


var word = new Array(3);
word[0] = "Michael";
word[1] = "Simon";
word[2] = "Peter";
word[3] = "Mark";

function random_word(){
var randomWord = word[Math.floor(Math.random()*word.length)]
}




var btn1 = document.getElementById("btnSurrender");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("btnWinning");
var pic = document.getElementById("photo");
var secondsP = document.getElementById('seconds');

var clock = null;


btn1.addEventListener("click", surrender);
btn2.addEventListener("click", winning);

function timer () {

random_word();

clearInterval(clock);

var start = new Date().getTime();

clock = setInterval(function() {



         pic.innerHTML='<img src="" alt="">';
         var seconds = Math.round(15 - (new Date().getTime() - start) / 1000);


         if (seconds >= 0) {
           secondsP.textContent = seconds;
         } else {
           clearInterval(clock);
         }

         if (seconds === 0) {
           pic.innerHTML='<img src="mops bops.png" alt="">';

         }
}, 1000);
}

function surrender(){

clearInterval(clock);
pic.innerHTML='<img src="mops bops.png" alt="">';
secondsP.textContent = 0;
setTimeout(timer,2000);
word[Math.floor(Math.random()*word.length)]
random_word();
}
function winning(){

clearInterval(clock);
pic.innerHTML='<img src="mopsik.jpg" alt="">';
secondsP.textContent = 0;
setTimeout(timer,2000);
word[Math.floor(Math.random()*word.length)]
random_word();
}

timer();

document.write(randomWord)
setInterval(timer, 17000)

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `var randomWord` is only defined within the function `random_word()`. It might be a scope problem (where a variable is visible is called "scope"). Trya console log right after `var randomWord = ...`. I think the line itself looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
var randomWord;
```

You need to arrow it at the beginning of the *script*, before giving a `document.write`

Comment: Hi, I didn't quite understand what should I put at the beginning of the script, "var randomWord;" or whole "random_word()" function. In first case it says: "undefined", so I called "random_word" function to define it. But it doesn't work at all, like in the second case. Can you explain what did you mean, please :) ?

Answer (score 0):

When I tested your code and set it to the "`randomWord`" variable at the beginning of the code, it worked; You should do the same, set the variable at the beginning of the code!

Comment: I have no idea what I do wrong but it always says "undefined". I did exactly what you wrote. I put "var randomWord" in the first place of the script. Is this only thing that I should do? Maybe I didn't understand sometning. Should I extra write this variable, or just pull it from my "random_word();" function. Please help.

Comment: This is how it looks like: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bys5fts5-EgiaXdVaW93Q2xjYTQ/view?usp=sharing